# WF4.5- Expression Activity type 'CSharpValue`1' requires compilation in order to run

Tags: c#, xaml, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

**Background**

What I'm trying to do is to have a scoped variable of one of my models in the xaml.

In my workflow project "MyProject.Workflows" I have created model classes, code activities and Xaml files. They are all under same namespace. In another project ("*Engine*"), I load and execute these workflows.

To load the workflows in the "*Engine*", I use `ActivityXamlServices` with `ActivityXamlServicesSettings` including `CompileExpressions = true`.

When loading the `ActivityXamlServices`, I use a `XamlXmlReader` with `XamlXmlReaderSettings` where I actually point to the "MyProject.Workflows" dll.

Since Both these projects are in the same solution I actually referred MyProject.Workflows in the "*Engine*".

Because Earlier, they were in different solutions, So when I tried to do this It gave me It cant find the "MyProject.Workflows" dll even though I point it in the `XamlXmlReaderSettings`.

Then I tried to load the dll to the app domain and then it worked.But I did not want to deal with App Domains so I decided to get both projects under one solution so I can refer the "MyProject.Workflows" in the "Engine".

**Issue:**

If I use one of those models inside of the Xaml as an expression like "Assign Activity" the Workflow isn't getting compiled when I try to execute this.

For example if I use this in an "Assign" activity having a scoped variable of type **MyObject**

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyProject.Workflows.Models.MyObject>(inputString);
```

I will get the below error message when I run the workflow.

```
NotSupportedException:'Expression Activity type 'CSharpValue`1' requires compilation in order to run.  Please ensure that the workflow has been compiled.
```

If I remove these objects and just deal with strings or ints, it works fine.

**Things I found in my research:**

1. I found this was a bug in .Net Framework 4.5. But Im using 4.6
2. Even though I used `CompileExpressions = true` , I tried this compile method I found. But did not change a thing.

   ```
    private static void Compile(DynamicActivity dynamicActivity)
   {
       TextExpressionCompilerSettings settings = new TextExpressionCompilerSettings
       {
           Activity = dynamicActivity,
           Language = "C#",
           ActivityName = dynamicActivity.Name.Split('.').Last() + "_CompiledExpressionRoot",
           ActivityNamespace = string.Join(".", dynamicActivity.Name.Split('.').Reverse().Skip(1).Reverse()),
           RootNamespace = null,
           GenerateAsPartialClass = false,
           AlwaysGenerateSource = true,
       };

       TextExpressionCompilerResults results =
           new TextExpressionCompiler(settings).Compile();
       if (results.HasErrors)
       {
           throw new Exception("Compilation failed.");
       }

       ICompiledExpressionRoot compiledExpressionRoot =
           Activator.CreateInstance(results.ResultType,
               new object[] { dynamicActivity }) as ICompiledExpressionRoot;
       CompiledExpressionInvoker.SetCompiledExpressionRootForImplementation(
           dynamicActivity, compiledExpressionRoot);
   }
   ```
3. I read that some people faced this problem and they had to actually move the models to a diffrent namespace. I did that too. Didn't fix the problem.

My Xaml file has this entry added at the top.

```
 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject.Workflows.Models"
```

Can someone please help me to get through this?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't the JSON.NET code that is causing the problem? Have you tried adding some code in the expression that only uses your models and not any other outside code?

Comment: @MattMilner I removed models completely from the solution and created a nuget package. Now its working. I dont fully understand the underlying problem. But I know its because assembly loading and namespaces.